# How to make columns not sortable in EditableGrid javascript library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, editablegrid

I would like to deny the columns sorting feature fired by clicking on the column header, but I can't find the property to set for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

```
editableGrid = new EditableGrid("DemoGridJsData");
editableGrid.enableSort=false;
```